# Java--I get an infinite loop when attempting to run my alphabetizer program. I can't seem to find the error

Tags: java

The code runs correctly until the for-loops. That's really all to it; I just can't seem to figure out why I'm getting an infinite loop. I've just been trying to sort the word "May" and "Code", so it outputs [Code, May].

```
import java.util.*;
public class Alphabetical 
{
    public static void main(String[]args) 
    {
        List<String>words = new ArrayList();
        String word = "";
        while(!word.equals("stop")) 
        {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a word. Enter 'stop' when finished.");
            word = s.nextLine();
            words.add(word);
        }
        words.remove(words.size()-1);
        System.out.print(words);
        String temp = "";
        boolean breakthis = false ;
        for(int i = words.size()-1; i >= 1;i--) 
        {
            if(breakthis)
                break;
            temp = words.get(i);
            for(int j = 0;j < words.size();i++) 
            {
                if(temp.charAt(0) == words.get(j).charAt(0))
                {
                    breakthis = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(temp.charAt(0) > words.get(j).charAt(0)) 
                {
                    words.add(j, temp);
                    words.remove(words.size()-1);
                    i = words.size()-1;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.print(words);    
    }

}
```

Comment: you wrote: `i++`, you meant: `j++` *(j remains 0, hence the loop)*  ;~p

Comment: I'm out of flags but this should be closed as a typo.